# Angular Route Guard Throws ZoneAwareError when Provided

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm learning Angular (upgrading from AngularJS 1.5 to Angular) and trying out the things I could do in v1.5 like guarding routes.

Using the AngularCLI I added a guard, but once it was provided to `canActivate` it throws this error:

```
ERROR ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
Error
    at Error.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfil…, rejection: Error, promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask}
```

If I use just `canActivate: []` the error disappears, but once it is `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` no matter what I do to the guard the error is always thrown.

I've also been following the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#routing-refactor) and if I replace the AuthGuard with the simplest example they provide in `src/app/auth-guard.service.ts (excerpt)` it still throws the same error.

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

**// APP-ROUTING.MODULE.TS**

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './core/auth.guard';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './core/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] // <-- throws error
    //canActivate: [] // <-- no error
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**// AUTH.GUARD.TS**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**// AUTH.GUARD.TS (simpler version from docs still fails)**

```ts
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called'); // never logs to console
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: try specifying only **boolean** return type for canActivate action an remove the _Observable, Promise_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, though there is no example in the docs provided.  The docs do indicate that in a single line that `Guards and the service providers they require must be provided at the module-level.` so I added it my `app.module.ts` under providers (as well as the service it uses) since it will be used throughout the application and it works now.

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';   
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module'; 
import { AuthGuard } from './core/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './core/auth.service'; // <-- also had to add  
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './core/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

// TODO: trim down imports and spread them into features like FormsModule and HttpModule
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // Angular modules
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    // Custom modules
    CoreModule,
    AuthModule,
    DashboardModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, AuthService], // <-- added here
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

put the guard where the the dashboard path is defined :

```
//...
{  path : 'dashboard',
   component : DashboardComponent
   canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
//...
```

Comment: Hi, sorry that redirect was a mistake.  I updated it to be the component.